# Exporting a Microsoft Access table to UTF-16 CSV

Tags: excel, ms-access, unicode, encoding, utf-16

I have an Access table with some Chinese characters that I need to export into a CSV file with UTF-16 encoding.  If this is not possible, I could also try exporting the table into an XLS or CSV file, and then convert the encoding to UTF-16.

I have a feeling there is no simple way of doing this using Access and/or Excel and/or VBA, but if there is, I would love to hear it!  If not, a solution using Java would be helpful.

I'm sure it would be helpful if I knew what encoding the file was already in.  The Chinese characters show up correctly when I export the file to Microsoft Excel 2000, but they do not show up correctly in Microsoft Access.  They were originally typed into Microsoft Excel.  I think that means they are in Unicode rich text, but I'm not sure.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

I use ADO streams to do this sort of thing. I had to do this for a TON of websites where I was helping them with SEO automation.

http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-convert-byte-array-utf8-string-vb6.asp

' accept a byte array containing utf-8 data
' and convert it to a string
Public Function ConvertStringToUtf8Bytes(ByRef strText As String) As Byte()

```
Dim objStream As ADODB.Stream
Dim data() As Byte

' init stream
Set objStream = New ADODB.Stream
objStream.Charset = "utf-16"
objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
objStream.Type = adTypeText
objStream.Open

' write bytes into stream
objStream.WriteText strText
objStream.Flush

' rewind stream and read text
objStream.Position = 0
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
objStream.Read 3 ' skip first 3 bytes as this is the utf-8 marker
data = objStream.Read()

' close up and return
objStream.Close
ConvertStringToUtf8Bytes = data
```

End Function